# Deleting missing files from your recently used files in Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10

How do I delete any recently used files from my recent files history but only remove those that no longer resides on my system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many threads relating to cleaning out the recently used files but those all remove everything.

This method allows you to keep those files that still reside on your system while removing those that are not.

You can download this [RecentFilesView - View the list of recently opened files](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/recent_files_view.html)

What this does is load all the recently used files in a simple UI and allows the user to pick and choose which to delete.

---

### How to delete the missing files and folders from your recent history list

Open  the [RecentFilesView.exe](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/recent_files_view.html) app, then:

1. Sort the missing column so that all the missing file(s) or folder(s) are together.
2. Click the first missing file and then shift-click the last missing one that are in the list to select the group. Or alternatively, you can ctrl+click individual item(s) in the list.
3. Press delete on the keyboard or click the X icon in the toolbar.

Now you have cleaned out your recently used files and folders that no longer exist on your system.

---

## Screenshot of app and steps

[image]